# Unable to Mount NTFS Drives after upgrading to 22.04

Tags: dual-boot, mount, ntfs, 22.04

It was working fine in 2.10. Now that I upgraded to 22.04, USB and my dual boot Windows 10 partitions in NTFS are not mounting. I tried Ventoy USB and it was working, was able to browse the contents.

Is there a way out? Thanks.

Comment: Did a Windows update turn fast start up back on? It may do that without you even knowing an update occurred. https://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/unable-to-mount-windows-10-partition-it-is-in-an-unsafe-state & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation

Comment: I am not sure. I was ok before the upgrade. And working now after the command in my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This command helps

sudo apt install ntfs-3g fuse

[Source](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-mount-partition-with-ntfs-file-system-and-read-write-access)

Comment: Thank you so much! For me `sudo apt install ntfs-3g` was enough (since I had `fuse3` already).

Comment: You are welcome :)